# Log in using Service Principal for assigning app roles to users

Tags: azure, azure-service-principal, azure-application-roles

I'm working on a script for adding app roles for given users. I can do so using the following HTTP call (Graph API):

```
curl --silent -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  -d "{\"appRoleId\":\"${AIRLOCK_MANAGER_ROLE_ID}\",\"principalId\":\"${AIRLOCK_MANAGER_USER}\",\"resourceId\":\"${WORKSPACE_APP_REG}\"}" \
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/${WORKSPACE_APP_REG}/appRoleAssignments
```

I acquire the token using my personal user with the Tenant. That's the user I use daily for regular work, and everything goes fine. It means I make the call and the app role is assigned to given user. For the moment the token is acquired, my user has `Privileged Role Administrator` enabled.

For login I use `az login`, and for acquiring the token I use `az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph`.

In production I want to use a service principal. Actually, this service principal belongs to the app registration to whom the target app role belongs to. I have created a secret, and acquired a token using:

```
az login --service-principal --allow-no-subscriptions --tenant "${TENANT_ID}" --username "${CLIENT_ID}" --password "${CLIENT_SECRET}"
```

Using this I can make the following call, for getting roles assigned to the target user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${AIRLOCK_MANAGER_USER}/appRoleAssignments
```

However, when trying to assign an app role using the same POST call shown above, I receive the following error message:

[image: Error message]

It's quite clear that the service principal doesn't have enough privileges. For solving this, I tried the following API permissions assginment:

[image: Permissions assignment]

Permissions `Application.Read.All` and `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` are assigned according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I have also tried `Application` type (with Admin consent granted) and received the same error message. After each change in permissions, I waited around 20 minutes.

Do you know which other permissions are supposed to be assigned?

**EDIT 1**

The problems were:

1. Token was acquired before permissions `Application.Read.All` and `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` were assigned.
2. Permissions `Application.Read.All` and `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` must be of `Application` type.

[image: Correct permissions]

The new token includes the required roles assigned:

[image]

Comment: While signing in as a service principal, you need to grant API permissions of **Application** type. After assigning these permissions, you need to acquire token again and use it to call Graph API.

Comment: @Sridevi You're correct. I already edited the question to inform my findings. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Instead of editing the question, post it in answer if your issue is resolved. You can check the added answer and let me know if any changes needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error occurred as you are using permissions of `Delegated` type while signing in as a **service principal**.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran the below script by signing as service principal with *Delegated* permissions:

```bash
az login --service-principal --allow-no-subscriptions --tenant "${TENANT_ID}" --username "${CLIENT_ID}" --password "${CLIENT_SECRET}"
TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph --query 'accessToken' --output tsv)

curl --silent -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  -d "{\"appRoleId\":\"${AIRLOCK_MANAGER_ROLE_ID}\",\"principalId\":\"${AIRLOCK_MANAGER_USER}\",\"resourceId\":\"${WORKSPACE_APP_REG}\"}" \
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/${WORKSPACE_APP_REG}/appRoleAssignments
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to grant permissions of **Application** type while signing in as *service principal* and acquire the token again.

[image]

If the error still persists, try assigning **Application Administrator** role to the service principal like this:

[image]

Now, I generated token again by running below script and got the **response** successfully like this:

```bash
az login --service-principal --allow-no-subscriptions --tenant "${TENANT_ID}" --username "${CLIENT_ID}" --password "${CLIENT_SECRET}"
TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph --query 'accessToken' --output tsv)

curl --silent -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  -d "{\"appRoleId\":\"${AIRLOCK_MANAGER_ROLE_ID}\",\"principalId\":\"${AIRLOCK_MANAGER_USER}\",\"resourceId\":\"${WORKSPACE_APP_REG}\"}" \
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/${WORKSPACE_APP_REG}/appRoleAssignments
```

**Response:**

[image]